# rails 3 nested resource form for works in New but not in Edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, form-for

I have a pretty straight forward nested form.

Categories has_many awards has_many recommendations.

So my recommendation form is a partial and the form_for leads off with:

```
<%= form_for [@category, @award, @recommendation], :url => category_award_recommendations_path(@category, @award, @recommendation),  :html => { :multipart => true}  do |f| %>
```

this works fine and processes for the #new form.  But when I mess with the #edit view it renders fine but when I submit it it uses the following url:

http://localhost:3000/categories/1/awards/1/recommendations.112

Question: 
Why does it render the "." instead of a "/"

Comment: Anyone?, I have not been able to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `category_award_recommendations_path`, when it should be `category_award_recommendation_path` (notice the `s` missing at the end of `recommendation`).

EDIT: This is the answer for

> Why does it render the "." instead of a "/"

Your form action url should change wether it's creating something or editing something. `form_for` does it itself when you don't supply the `:url` option, based on wether the object is persisted or not.